# How can I resolve from the IServiceProvider from inside my classes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I starting to learn changes in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)
and cannot find how to get `IServiceProvider`, for example in "Model"'s method

```
public class Entity 
{
     public void DoSomething()
     { 
           // This next line doesn't compile.
           // Where is ServiceContainer or something like that?
           var dbContext = ServiceContainer.GetService<DataContext>();
     }
}
```

I know, we configuring services at startup, but where all service collection staying or `IServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 70):

You have to bring in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace to gain access to the generic

```
GetService<T>();
```

extension method that should be used on

```
IServiceProvider
```

Also note that you can directly inject services into controllers in ASP.NET 5. See below example.

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    string ServiceValue { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceImplementation : ISomeService
{
    public ServiceImplementation()
    {
        ServiceValue = "Injected from Startup";
    }

    public string ServiceValue { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, ServiceImplementation>();
}
```

HomeController

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...
public IServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
public ISomeService InjectedService { get; set; }

public HomeController(IServiceProvider provider, ISomeService injectedService)
{
    Provider = provider;
    InjectedService = Provider.GetService<ISomeService>();
}
```

Either approach can be used to get access to the service. Additional service extensions for Startup.cs

```
AddInstance<IService>(new Service())
```

A single instance is given all the time. You are responsible for initial object creation.

```
AddSingleton<IService, Service>()
```

A single instance is created and it acts like a singleton.

```
AddTransient<IService, Service>()
```

A new instance is created every time it is injected.

```
AddScoped<IService, Service>()
```

A single instance is created inside of the current HTTP Request scope. It is equivalent to Singleton in the current scope context.

**Updated 18 October 2018**

See: [aspnet GitHub - ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs)

Comment: This does not seem to work in `ASP.NET 5` which is what the OP is about. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It's changed since this post. If I'm not mistaken, this was as of Beta 7? This is definitely in reference to ASP.NET 5. They renamed the namespace from Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. Here's where the GetService<T> extension is defined: https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs

Comment: Hmmm... just tried: DNX 4.6 `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` and `GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()`; results in the error, `The name 'GetService' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: See revised answer for implementation.

Comment: same concept as Angular :)

Comment: GitHub link is returning 404.

Comment: isn't it a bad practice to pass IServiceProvider to the controller which is a reference to the container rather than passing the dependency itself?

Comment: @SimpleFellow - I was thinking in the same line. By passing IServiceProvider  then the pattern will just be "passing locator object around" using DI. But after coding with this pattern for a while I start to think that the practicality of passing IServiceProvider deserves a second thought, for me, at least on job services (maybe not in rest apis).

Comment: One more comment, I do find that java/android dagger better in this sense, as it does not require a lot of parameters to be added to an existing constructor.  The attributes look clear to me. Don't they look clear to you?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is a good idea for an entity (or a model) to have access to any service.

Controllers, on the other hand, do have access to any registered service in their constructors, and you don't have to worry about it.

```cs
public class NotifyController : Controller
{
    private static IEmailSender emailSender = null;
    protected static ISessionService session = null;
    protected static IMyContext dbContext = null;
    protected static IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment = null;

    public NotifyController(
                IEmailSender mailSenderService,
                IMyContext context,
                IHostingEnvironment env,
                ISessionService sessionContext)
    {
        emailSender = mailSenderService;
        dbContext = context;
        hostingEnvironment = env;
        session = sessionContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I think it's too:)

Answer (score 4):

use **GetRequiredService** instead of **GetService**, like the example on ASP.NET Core tutorials ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql )

documentation on the method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceProviderServiceExtensions_GetRequiredService__1_System_IServiceProvider_

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

      using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(serviceProvicer.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `GetService()`

The difference between GetService and GetRequiredService is related with exception.

GetService() returns null if a service does not exist.
GetRequiredService() will throw exception.

```
public static class ServiceProviderServiceExtensions
{
    public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        return (T)provider.GetService(typeof(T));
    }

    public static T GetRequiredService<T>(this IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        return (T)provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you want to have the DI do its thing and inject that for you:

```
public class Entity 
{
    private readonly IDataContext dbContext;

    // The DI will auto inject this for you
    public class Entity(IDataContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         // dbContext is already populated for you
         var something = dbContext.Somethings.First();
     }
}
```

However, `Entity` would have to be automatically instantiated for you... like a `Controller` or a `ViewComponent`. If you need to manually instantiate this from a place where this `dbContext` is not available to you, then you can do this:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

public class Entity 
{
    private readonly IDataContext dbContext;

    public class Entity()
    {
        this.dbContext = (IDataContext)CallContextServiceLocator.Locator.ServiceProvider
                            .GetService(typeof(IDataContext));
    }

     public void DoSomething()
     {
         var something = dbContext.Somethings.First();
     }
}
```

But just to emphasize, this is considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. And... at the risk of making some pattern people really upset... if all else fails, you can add a `static IContainer` in a helper class or something and assign it in your `StartUp` class in the `ConfigureServices` method: `MyHelper.DIContainer = builder.Build();` And this is a really ugly way to do it, but sometimes you just need to get it working.

Comment: This is a perfect example of "how many ways NOT to do dependency injection"

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP is getting confused. Entities should be as “thin” as possible. They should try not to contain logic, and or external references other than navigation properties. Look up some common patterns like repository pattern which helps to abstract your logic away from the entities themselves

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting your service inline, try injecting it into the constructor.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient(typeof(DataContext));
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public Entity(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // use _context here
    }
}
```

I also suggest reading up on what `AddTransient` means, as it will have a significant impact on how your application shares instances of DbContext. This is a pattern called [Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection). It takes a while to get used to, but you will never want to go back once you do.

Comment: thanks for answer, but if i have many entities i need to rewrite constructors, and can't using Activator.CreateInstance, 
using injection in method arguments looks ugly, can u tell me good patern with YAGNI following ?

Comment: Are you trying to use Entity Framework? Injection is used in constructors, not methods. I'm unsure what you mean with YAGNI in this context.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Entity Framework, but look at this case:
I have entity, for example - Catalog,
and Catalog have property - Url,
in old MVC i can just create httpcontext wrapper and use url helper inside property,
in new MVC i can't do this, and have no variants except include IUrlHelper in Method(adding new Method wrapper on property Path)
for DRY, but this is still so weird

Comment: I believe the exercise that @Sam is referencing comes from the following:

http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html

In this exercise, they explicitly use the generic GetService extension method defined in Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Its ok for constructor injection, but how about EF, do they inject objects while materializing from database ? 
@Anton

Comment: Why would an entity need to have a reference to its context?