# What is the purpose of IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, interface, asp.net-core-2.0

I am implementing a new .NET Core project and working on dependency injection for my service layer. I created an interface that implements `IServiceProvider` and now must implement `GetService(Type serviceType)`. This is my interface.

```
public interface INewsService : IServiceProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetAllSources();
}

public class NewsService : INewsService
{
    private readonly INewsRepository _newsRepository;

    public NewsService(INewsRepository newsRepository)
    {
        _newsRepository = newsRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllSources()
    {
        return _newsRepository.GetAllSources();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of the method? Reading through the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.getservice(v=vs.110).aspx), it's really vague and doesn't clear it up too much. My code runs when I start it...so I'm not sure what it is needed for.

Comment: Why do you want to implement `IServiceProvider`? There is some context missing from your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Gets the service object of the specified type.

You should not implement `IServiceProvider` on `INewsService` interface.

`IServiceProvider` desribes factory to create instances of your services:

```
IServiceProvider provider = GetServiceProvider();
var newsService = provider.GetService(typeof(INewsService));
```

Read more about service provider: [IServiceProvider in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990618/iserviceprovider-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 8):

`IServiceProvider` is the interface that implements the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. In general, it is for internal use by ASP.NET Core.

What you are supposed to do is implement your own service interfaces:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Then build your own concrete types:

```
public class Something : ISomething
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

You would then register it with the DI container like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<ISomething, Something>();
}
```

And you can use your service throughout ASP.NET Core by accepting it as a parameter in a constructor. For example, here is how you would use it in `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISomething something;

    public HomeController(ISomething something)
    {
        this.something = something ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(something));
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        something.DoSomething();

        return View();
    }
}
```

`IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)` is called internally when the constructor argument is resolved to get your service from the container (when `HomeController` is instantiated in this example). It is not required to implement `IServiceProvider` to use dependency injection with ASP.NET Core, you would only implement it if you wanted to provide some custom functionality that the DI container doesn't already have.

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time to type a response. My question really was only about IServiceProvider, not interfaces in general.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to look at this answer :[GetService()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317400/6393097)
If you have many services come to the controller

```
    private readonly IMarkService _markService;
    private readonly IModelService _modelService;
    private readonly IModificationService _modificationService;

    public CatalogController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _markService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMarkService>();
        _modelService = serviceProvider.GetService<IModelService>();
        _modificationService = serviceProvider.GetService<IModificationService>();
    }
```

Comment: Using the service provider in a controller is anti-pattern and should be discouraged. Use constructor injection instead.